# shieldUI grid filter / sort persistence on grid refresh

Tags: sorting, filter, grid, selection, shieldui

Is it possible to persist grid sort/filter/selection on grid.refresh() in some smart optimized way? I need to refresh grid on window resize event to adjust to a new window size. I guess refresh internally destroys and recreates grid, not accounting for possible active sort/filter/selection. Because grid can contain a lot of data (virtual scrolling), I would like to a avoid unnecessary db querying, rendering and sorting. I guess I am looking for a refresh which will refresh on existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in refresh method it self. It accepts options objects where one can provide current data source options to persist. Example to persist sort and/or filter:

```
var options = {
    dataSource: $("#grid").swidget().dataSource
}
$("#grid").swidget().refresh(options);
```

Please stand me correct if I am wrong here. For selections I guess one can retrieve selected indices and reselect after calling refresh.

EDIT: filter and sort are preserved, but filter row resets (loses all active input values). Could this be a bug? How to keep values in filter row?

Answer (score 1):

Seams like they just implemented it - here is the [example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/filtering).

Maybe to be included in the next release.

Here is the code in the example that does this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#grid").shieldGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: gridData,
            schema: {
                fields: {
                    id: { type: Number },
                    name: { type: String },
                    company: { type: String },
                    phone: { type: String },
                    age: { type: Number },
                    gender: { type: String }
                }
            },
            filter: {
                // create the initial filter in that form
                and: [
                    { path: "name", filter: "con", value: "John" }
                ]
            }
        },
        filtering: {
            enabled: true
        },
        paging: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "id", width: "250px", title: "ID" },
            { field: "name", title: "Person Name", width: "250px" },
            { field: "company", title: "Company" },
            { field: "phone", title: "Phone", width: "250px" },
            { field: "age", title: "Age" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: please post your answer using that example.